# Concatenate columns and return only distinct value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to concatenate columns and only return distinct value

| Column |
| --- |
| First,Second,Third |
| Second |
| Second,Third,Four |

Expected Output:

| Column |
| --- |
| First |
| Second |
| Third |
| Four |

Currently, this is what I have:

```
select *
from dbo.Test t 
cross apply string_split(t.Column, ',') cs
```

The result that I'm getting is not correct.
Please help.

Comment: You probably just need a sub-query to get the distinct results?

Comment: If you want **distinct** values - why do you have `Second` twice in your expected results? And why is `Third` missing completely?

Comment: @marc_s - I'm going to guess a typo

Comment: yes, it was a typo. I have fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this will do the trick

```
CREATE TABLE #t (val varchar(100));

INSERT INTO #t
VALUES ('First,Second,Third'),
('Second'),
('Second,Third,Fourth');

SELECT 
    DISTINCT cs.value
FROM #t t
CROSS APPLY string_split(t.val, ',') cs;

DROP TABLE #t;
```

Comment: This will not produce the order shown in the question. Maybe the order doesn't matter, but maybe it's just the crucial point.

Comment: @JonasMetzler - admittedly, I've assumed a typo in the OP's "expected results" - ie, they are actually after First, Second, Third, Four.  And, yeah, I guess OP can modify as needed if they particularly want to ensure sort order of results

Comment: @Craig Thanks. That helps me solve the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

I read the question as it is quite important and intended to keep the original "order", meaning the result should be sorted by their distinct occurence. So I assume the result should be exactly

| Column |
| --- |
| First |
| Second |
| Third |
| Four |

I also like the idea to use `STRING_SPLIT`, but this "alone" produces this result:

| Column |
| --- |
| First |
| Four |
| Second |
| Third |

One way to enforce the sorting is to combine `ROW_NUMBER` with `STRING_SPLIT`, something like this:

```
WITH sorting AS
(SELECT yourcolumn, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY yourcolumn) AS rowNr 
FROM test)
SELECT split.value
FROM sorting s
CROSS APPLY string_split(s.yourcolumn, ',') split 
GROUP BY split.value
ORDER BY MIN(s.rowNr);
```

See here a working example which shows both results: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ye6oEFl-)

Comment: Even though I do not need sorting, but I like your way to solve the problem. This will be served as a future reference. thank you